# Understanding ASP.Net toolbar controls

Tags: asp.net

I am new to ASP.Net and am looking for a resource to describe the asp.net controls in the toolbar. Any ideas and suggestions are greatly apreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[System.Web.UI.WebControls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.aspx) on MSDN would be a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

Two places to look at are:

- [Web Page Controls (How Do I in Visual Web Developer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186113.aspx) in MSDN
- [http://www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/) (seems to be down or very slow right now)